# Recover font antialias on Yosemite

Tags: font, display, defaults

I've changed some options related to font rendering by `defaults write` command in past (I can't recall was it `lcdfilter`, or something else).
Now when I turn off antialiasing in system preferences font are still looks antialiased, but have less weight (see screenshots).
[image: 1. With antialiasing]
[image: 2. Without antialiasing]
[image: 2. With antialiasing]
[image: 2. Without antialiasing]

Note, I have Retina display, so, this could be normal behaviour, but I'm not certain, that's why I decided to ask about it.
If this is not default behaviour (it seems to me, that fonts too heavy when antialiasing turned on), how can I rollback changed values to defaults?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the amount of font smoothing with the following command:

```
defaults write -g AppleFontSmoothing -int [value]
```

`[value]` is a value between 0 and 3 inclusive. Requires log out and log in.

[Here's a gif by Lauri](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/60065) showing the difference:

> [image]

Comment: Oh, I suppose this is exactly the same command I've used, but what is actual default value?

Comment: @Geradlus_RU `2` should be default.

Comment: OK, I'll try it out now. __UPD__ I have 3 set for now.

Comment: Well, I've changed value to `2`, logged out and in, but actually there is no difference. At least I know default value now, thanks!